# How do I infer the usage of parentheses when translating an expression tree?

Tags: .net, translation, expression-trees, parentheses, inorder

I am working on translating an expression tree to a format that resembles infix notation; I am not evaluating the tree or executing its operations.  The tree contains both logical and relational operations, and I would like to emit parentheses in an intelligent manner during the translation.

To illustrate, consider the following contrived expression:

```
a < x & (a < y | a == c) & a != d
```

If I walk the expression tree produced by this expression in-order, then I will print out the following expression, which is incorrect.

```
a < x & a < y | a == c & a != d
// equivalent to (a < x & a < y) | (a == c & a != d)
```

Alternatively, I can again perform an in-order traversal but emit parentheses before and after processing a binary expression.  This will produce the following correct expression, but with several redundant parentheses.

```
(((a < x) & ((a < y) | (a == c))) & (a != d))
```

Is there an expression tree traversal algorithm that produces optimally-parenthesized expressions?

For reference, here is a snippet of the [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) I am using to inspect the tree.

```
class MyVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        Console.Write("(");

        Visit(node.Left);
        Console.WriteLine(node.NodeType.ToString());
        Visit(node.Right);

        Console.Write(")");

        return node;
    }

    // VisitConstant, VisitMember, and VisitParameter omitted for brevity.
}
```

Comment: +1 and fav'd, have been struggeling with this before. I believe there are approached based on passing the current operator's precedence around, but we'll see.

Comment: I found the following post which suggests a method similar to Dialecticus' below.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176650/detect-parenthesis-in-binaryexpression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this, assuming that `node.NodeType` is of type `NodeType`, and that function `Precedes` exists and returns true if first parameter precedes the second.

```
protected override Expression Visit(BinaryExpression node, NodeType parentType)
{
    bool useParenthesis = Precedes(parentType, node.NodeType);

    if (useParenthesis)
        Console.Write("(");

    Visit(node.Left, node.NodeType);
    Console.WriteLine(node.NodeType.ToString());
    Visit(node.Right, node.NodeType);

    if (useParenthesis)
        Console.Write(")");

    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've accepted the [answer of Dialecticus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12058355/131407) as it provides a good basis for implementing this algorithm.  The only issue with this answer is that it requires that the `VisitBinary()` method know about its parent caller as a method argument, which is not feasible since these methods are overloads of a base method.

I provide the following solution, which uses a similar algorithm, but applies the check to emit parentheses in the parent call for the child nodes of the expression tree.

```
class MyVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly IComparer<ExpressionType> m_comparer = new OperatorPrecedenceComparer();

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        Visit(node, node.Left);
        Console.Write(node.NodeType.ToString());
        Visit(node, node.Right);

        return node;
    }

    private void Visit(Expression parent, Expression child)
    {
        if (m_comparer.Compare(child.NodeType, parent.NodeType) < 0)
        {
            Console.Write("(");
            base.Visit(child);
            Console.Write(")");
        }
        else
        {
            base.Visit(child);
        }
    }

    // VisitConstant, VisitMember, and VisitParameter omitted for brevity.
}
```

The precedence comparison function is implemented as an `IComparer<ExpressionType>`, which applies the C# rules of [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

```
class OperatorPrecedenceComparer : Comparer<ExpressionType>
{
    public override int Compare(ExpressionType x, ExpressionType y)
    {
        return Precedence(x).CompareTo(Precedence(y));
    }

    private int Precedence(ExpressionType expressionType)
    {
        switch(expressionType) { /* group expressions and return precedence ordinal * }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Precedence function?

Comment: You just need to enumerate the operators according to the precedence rules in a function, then make the encompassing class implement `IComparable`.  I don't have the code handy, but it is straightforward if you think about it.